# How to input data from chrome.storage.sync into a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome-extension, storage

I'm trying to capture data in chrome.storage.sync (which is hopefully working in the options.js file) and then 'get' this data for input into a form that is in the form of an iframe that opens. Currently I have the code for this .js file contained within a variable: it captures what is input into the form and turns it into data: this works at the moment. But I want for the form, when it first loads, to get the value stored in sync and put it into the form.

I've tried it within the variable but I think I've set this up so it only does something when 'save' is clicked so it wouldn't run the code.
I now have it outside of this main variable.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function insertId (){

var useridsync = chrome.storage.sync.get([theUserid]);

var useridget = document.getElementById("userid").value = useridsync;

};);
```

Comment: The storage API is asynchronous so this not how it should be used. Instead of inventing things simply use the examples in the documentation. In this case it'll be something like chrome.storage.sync.get(theUserid, e => { document.getElementById("userid").value = e[theUserid] });

Comment: Thanks for the code, it's less invention and more experimentation whilst trying to learn. Would I just stick in that code "chrome.storage.sync.get(theUserid, e => { document.getElementById("userid").value = e[theUserid] });" as is?

Comment: Yes, if `theUserid` is a string that contains the user id. Otherwise you'll need to adapt it somehow.

Comment: `theUserid` should be the key set in the options page -> `function save_userid() {
 var userid = document.getElementById('userid').value;
 chrome.storage.sync.set({
  theUserid: userid
 }`

Comment: In that case `theUserid` should be in quotes: chrome.storage.sync.get('theUserid', .......

Comment: the error I'm getting now is "Error handling response: ReferenceError: theUserid is not defined"

Comment: You also need to quote the second instance like `e['theUserid']` or use `e.theUserid`

Comment: THANK YOU! It finally works! Thanks for your patience @wOxxOm with the n00b!